# Windows 10: How do I print to an HP LaserJet 1320?

Tags: windows, network-printer

I have an old HP LaserJet 1320 that is shared on my home network via CUPS and Samba. It has worked well until I recently upgraded to Windows 10. Windows does not automatically detect the drivers for it and the generic drivers on the HP website, depending on my Windows connection method, either do not talk to the printer or produce a black block where each line should be.

How can I make Windows 10 talk to this printer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click **Windows Update** button
2. Wait until windows refreshes the list of drivers
3. Choose your printer

[image: Check this image]

Comment: This appears to be working well. Thanks for the update, I have changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in `HP LaserJet 2200 Series PCL 5` drivers on Windows 10.

The HP Laserjet 1320 supports PCL 5 and appears to be compatible. It may not provide all of the same quality options and features, but it allows basic printing for me. Tested against a Samba 4 server as well as a CUPS URL. Both worked in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I have a USB connection to my computer.  Had the same issue of it not working.  I do not know if this will solve the problem if it is another type of connection.

> When computer is off  unplugged USB connector.
>
> Downloaded generic driver from HP 1320 product page on HP.com
>
> When installing there is the option to select "USB"
>
> Completed installation.
>
> I plugged in USB connector.  I believe it is safer to plug it in when computer is off, but I do not know if Windows will still detect the printer.
>
> Windows automatically detected my printer.

Comment: "I do not know if this will solve the problem if it is another type of connection." > it's not an answer then. OP is using CUPS and Samba not USB.

Comment: I tried this for both a CUPS URI and via Microsoft's network sharing (SMB). I couldn't get these drivers to behave for a networked printer. I was routed repeatedly to HP's management window which had difficulty talking to the printer. When it did connect, I got black blocks where each printed line should be.

Answer (score 0):

download the universal printer driver for windows 7, works fine with windows 10. The driver provided by windows update doesn't support some of the features.

Comment: I had tried the universal printer drivers from the HP website without any luck. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make LaserJet 1320n work (Win 7 enterprise; win 10) in my case was:

1. Connect the printer in the net (modem)
2. Download upd-pcl5-x64-6.1.0.20062.exe
3. Run it: unzips files to a folder
4. You are asked: what alternative: 1 (traditional: creates a permanent object in 'Printers' file)
5. You are asked: Find printers: My printer is older, help me find it
6. A printer is found: 'hp LaserJet 1329 series (Hewlett-Packart)'
7. You can rename the printer, default: 'HP Universal Printing PCL5'
8. The printer is installed
9. You are asked: Share this printer so that others can find it and use it; OK
10. You are told: 'Added HP Universal Printing PCL5'
11. You are told: 'Print a test page'
12. You are told:  'Test page sent to printer', and sent a message: '... Work sent to a printer'